# .htaccess website.com/jp to website.com/lang=jp

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I need to redirect people who type

**domain.com/jp** or **www.domain.com/jp**

to

**www.domain.com/lang=jp**

My .htaccess already includes this

```
RewriteEngine On
rewritecond %{http_host} ^domain.com$ [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ http://www.domain.com/lang=$1 [R=302,nc]
```

Change `R=302` to `R-301` when you are sure the redirect works.

EDIT:

```
RedirectMatch 302 /jp http://www.domain.com/lang=jp
RedirectMatch 302 /cz http://www.domain.com/lang=cz
RedirectMatch 302 /eng http://www.domain.com/lang=eng
RedirectMatch 302 /en http://wwwdomain.com/lang=en
```

Comment: Does not work, seems like an infinity loop. Result: http://www.domain.com/lang=lang=lang=lang=lang=lang=lang=lang=lang=lang=lang=lang=lang=lang=lang=lang=lang=lang=lang=lang=jp

Comment: "Seems like an infinity loop", what do you mean by that? Is that the message that comes up?

Comment: When I type www.mydomain.com its pauses for a second, then redirects to www.mydomain.com/lang=lang=lang=lang=lang=lang=lang=lang=lang=lang=lang=lang=lang=lang=lang=lang=lang=lang=lang=lang=jp

Comment: Okay, is it just `jp` you want redirected or anything that is typed?

Comment: **jp**, **cz**, **eng** and **en**

Comment: Okay since it's only those specific ones, I have edited my post. Again change the `302` to `301` if the rules work